# Combining 2 drupal 7 sites - how to move modules?

Tags: migrations, multi-sites, backups

I am combining 2 drupal sites in to one, was not really my decision. What things I should be careful of and what pitfalls to avaoid?

List of things I will be combining

1. Content Types - Bundle copy module
2. View - Export functionality
3. Content Data - Feeds Importer
4. Blocks - Block Import Export module
5. Modules - I am going to install the standard modules from drupal projects and copy over any custom modules. How can I move the modules configurations?
6. Menus - How to move over the menus settings?
7. Users - Do not need to be migrated

There is not much taxonomy on the other site.
Anything else I am missing ?
Any suggestions on the sequence to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaMohan I updated the question. How do I move the modules specific settings though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for the menus, but for modules that doesn't implement any export functionality (either custom or contrib), take a look into the 'variables' table.

for how unpractical it may sounds, export the table data, keep only the 'module_*' entries of the module you need and insert the in the new site database, after you install the modules. You will have to change the sql from inserts to updates too.

yes, extremely unpractical, but i can't think to an automated routine for it.

also, probably you are forgetting to export users too (and custom roles).

Comment: Thanks, Users do not have to be migrated so can be skipped. Updating the question.